# Will it be possible to get a contract's balance by block number in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Will it be possible to get address state **at a given block** within smart contract execution logic?

Something like:
`block(10297202).(address('Ox...').balance)`

I assume it's not possible currently due to:

1. Miners do not hold the whole chain (In general).
2. Computational power will be added to every block generation.
3. [Question regarding reading past events info in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1895/can-a-contract-listen-to-events-of-another-contract)

Comment: Only archive nodes hold this information: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84199/state-only-node/84200#84200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible in solidity. The EVM doesn't have an opcode that can return that value. The BALANCE opcode returns the current balance of an address.