# Can we find previous balance values of state trie

Tags: etherscan, storage, state-trie

I know that in the block is included the StateRoot of the state trie. Also, i know that the entire state trie is saved locally on disk for each node and periodically be updated based on new upcoming transactions. My question now is any way to iterate back, for example, in block(n-1)  and find the balance of the state tie there? Or it's impossible because state trie keeps only the updated values?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive nodes store the full historical states.

Full nodes may store the historical state a few blocks back.

[More information about archive nodes here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/99124/620).

Comment: So if i understand correctly with Archive nodes we can retrieve the past account balances per block(historical state) for example, in block(n-1) and find the balance of the state tie there even if its an expensive operation am i right?

Comment: That is correct @MixalisNavridis