# Does blockchain state information take up space?

Tags: chaindata, state

When synchronising a new full node, the first step is to download all the available blocks, it's interesting to note that the node is not usable right away as it needs to pull from the network all the states the blockchain needs to be in the actual "state".

The question is, does all this new data take up space or it simply rewrites data in each block leaving the chain data size unchanged?

Thank you

Comment: It takes up space

Comment: How can I know the actual number of states in the mainnet ?

Comment: How can I know the actual number of states in the mainnet ?

Comment: I am not sure of my answer, I am just expressing my opinion, and I would like to know the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, does all this new data take up space or it simply rewrites data in each block leaving the chain data size unchanged?

There are two normal operating modes for Ethereum nodes: [full node and archive node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84200/620).

The full node automatically prunes the old state as you say. The full node is the default mode. The disk space requirements for the archive node are much higher, several terabytes.

[More information about the state scaling issues here](https://capitalgram.com/posts/scaling-evm/).

Comment: So lets say all the blocks are 400GB, syncing the state of the chain makes it always 400GB right?

Comment: No, because there is Merkle Tree overhead on the state. Please see the post I linked.

Comment: Does it add significat space respective to the actual size of the blocks?

Comment: A good question: it was discussed by Vitalik here https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/06/18/verkle.html - but I guess no one has run the figures against the production data

Answer (score 0):

Each account fits within 128 bytes, there are 160 million of accounts so the state takes up about 19 Gigs if we extract only the info that matters. However there are supporting data structures to hold this , like Patricia Merkle Trie and frozen chain data (blocks, transactions) which take up about 400 GB on disk as of 23 Jul 2021.

The data will keep growing with time, so if you want to "compress" it, re-download the chain periodically as it is the best way to compact it.

Comment: It is no longer necessary to re-download the chain since snap sync and pruning has been implemented (Geth 1.10.0).

Comment: @Undead8 and Level DB also defragments its files when keys are deleted?

Comment: @Undead8 yeah thats much more efficient!