# How wallets sync blocks after consensus happen

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, blocks, clients

i know that when user submits a transaction that transaction is then sent to all their peers by following this protocol https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol. Miners receive this transaction, check for validity and other things (like orphaned transactions), then bundle it together with a bunch of other transactions in a block they finally reach consensus and they store the block in the blockchain.

What happened with the wallet clients as they are not part of consensus how did they receive the blocks?? from my understanding they connect into a  P2P network and something like gossipnig happens between them and the validator peers who participate in consensus and finally, they sync blocks

Am i correct until now?

My second question is gossiping protocols usually gossip a message by passing it from neighbor to neighbor as a result when a client wallet connects to a peer whos taking part in consensus and try to sync blocks how client wallet knows that this peer does not produce fake blocks or forks.
Maybe the client sync from all active peers and follows the majority????

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes receive the same blocks and block headers from several nodes. If there a fork it is assumed the majority fork will always win long term and a PoW protocol has statistical finally. In fact, Ethereum mainnet has minor forks several times a day.

[If a node cannot get enough blocks to decide the correct course of action because all peers are ba, it is called Sybil attack](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/).

Comment: First of all thnx for your answer, i appreciate it i upvote it but before marking it as accepted i want a clarification. i am not talking for the consensus part i am talking after the consensus how a wallet sync/downloads blocks from nodes. You said "Nodes receive the same blocks and block headers from several nodes" do you refer to wallet nodes right? if yes please define the "receive from several nodes? does wallet selects randomly several node download blocks and check if the same? something like this its not clear to me?

Comment: [Wallet nodes are called full nodes and they are not different from other nodes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/84200/620). And you are correct, nodes cross-reference data across all their peers and will ban connections from nodes feeding invalid data.

Comment: hi again here is relate question if you know the answer thnaks in advance https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134114/kademlia-how-does-ethereum-uses-node-discovery-protocol-to-avoid-sybil-eclipse