# Kademlia: How does Ethereum uses node discovery protocol to avoid sybil/eclipse attacks?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, transactions, attacks

I want to describe a case that's not clear to me. let's say we have 10 peer validator nodes who reach consensus and agree to store some blocks on their chain. Let's say now that a wallet wants to sync some blocks. It connects to the kademlia P2P discovery protocol to find active validator peers and sync blocks(no participation in consensus only sync) and cross-reference data across all their peers.

How we can ensure that the kademlia P2P network is not flooded with malicious users trying to feed malicious blocks to the users that trying to sync? Is any authentication/validation mechanism exists?? Is there any bootstrap node in kademlia that decides where to give access?

**Attention!!** I am not talking for the consensus part that's easy to understand who doesn't obey protocol and ignore I am talking for case nodes want sync blocks, how do they trust them?